# In Vim how to jump between two files

Tags: vim

I need to jump back and forth between two files in Vim.

I can do this manually as `:e file1.txt` followed by `:e file2.txt`.  Is there a shortcut to directly jump to the previously opened file?

Note: I don't want to open the two files in split windows or multiple tabs.

I'm looking for something like `[ctrl + o]`, only the jump should be to previous file, not previous location in the same file

thanks for any hints

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use `<C-^>` or `<C-6>`.

From `:h ctrl-^`:

```
Edit the alternate file. Mostly the alternate file is
the previously edited file. This is a quick way to
toggle between two files. It is equivalent to ":e #",
except that it also works when there is no file name.

If the 'autowrite' or 'autowriteall' option is on and
the buffer was changed, write it.
Mostly the ^ character is positioned on the 6 key,
pressing CTRL and 6 then gets you what we call CTRL-^.
But on some non-US keyboards CTRL-^ is produced in
another way.
```

Answer (score 10):

This is a topic of file and buffer management. You can check related docs. I come up with some commands you may be interested:

`CTRL+^`: go to the last edited file in the same window.

`gf`: go to a file if the link under the cursor can be located.

`:bn` `:bp`: go to the next or previous buffer.

`:n` `:N`: go to the next or previous arg file.

And there is a plugin called [unimpaired](https://github.com/tpope/vim-unimpaired) which make you more happy!

If you want to jump to a file as you wish:

`:b partial_word` then press `Tab`, you will get auto completion.

`:ls` then `:b a_number` to go to that buffer.

Some plugins like bufexplorer, nerdtree is very useful. But in this situation, you may consider [CtrlP](https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim), which search all files very quickly!

Answer (score 8):

I am not sure I understand correctly, but with only two files opened maybe `buffer next` `:bn` will be enough?

Comment: That does exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

To really switch between two files, use `:b#`: this is more handy when you have more than two files open.

Say, you have `file1`, `file2`, `file3` loaded and want to flip between `2` and `3`:

- `:b file2` opens file2
- `:b file3` opens file3
- from now on, `:b#` switches from 3 to 2 and vice versa.

In this situation, `:bn` will loop through 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, ...

Answer (score 2):

I don't know a better solution, but one possible one is to just follow these steps:

```
:e file1.txt
:e file2.txt
: <commands commands>
:e <UP_ARROW> / <DOWN_ARROW> to switch between the files
```

This isn't probably what you asked for, but takes advantage of the autocomplete feature.

Answer (score 2):

If I get your question right, this is `:e#`

Answer (score 0):

I use :bn to goto the next open file, but since I'm lazy I
remap N so all I have to do is a shift-n ... very fast!

(Bonus question: What is that ^Z for?
A: That is a carryover from my SCO days when I would fat finger ctrl-z
and pop vi into a background job...I should remove it, but memories...)

This is my gvimrc that use to customize Vim on every Windows box I work on:

" custom gvimrc
" The commands in this are executed when the GUI is started.
" slc 07/05/2013 - default (normally c:\program files\Vim)

set ruler

set tabstop=3

set shiftwidth=3

set expandtab

set nobackup

set backupdir=C:\Windows\Temp

set dir=C:\Windows\Temp

colorschem torte

set nohlsearch

map N :bn

map ZZ :xa

map ^Z :No Jobs...NOT used in Vim...

syntax on